# Only show one row per title in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select distinct p.title, e.first_name, e.last_name, max(e.salary)
 from employees as e
 inner join employees_projects as ep
 on e.id = ep.employee_id
 inner join projects as p
 on p.id = ep.project_id
 group by 1,2,3
 order by p.title
```

Which returns multiple rows per title. I only want the max salary for each title.

```
          title           | first_name | last_name |  max  
--------------------------+------------+-----------+-------
 Build a cool site        | Cailin     | Ninson    | 30000
 Build a cool site        | Ian        | Peterson  | 80000
 Build a cool site        | Mike       | Peterson  | 20000
 Design 3 New Silly Walks | Ava        | Muffinson | 10000
 Update TPS Reports       | John       | Smith     | 20000
```

Tweaked @zealous code and this works:

```
 select
    title,
    first_name, 
    last_name,
    salary
from
(select 
    distinct p.title, 
    e.first_name, 
    e.last_name,
    e.salary,
    dense_rank() over (partition by p.title order by e.salary desc) as rnk
 from employees as e
 inner join employees_projects as ep
 on e.id = ep.employee_id
 inner join projects as p
 on p.id = ep.project_id
 group by 1,2,3, 4
 ) t
 where rnk = 1
 order by title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this window function `dense_rank()`. If there is tie in salary then it will return both records with max salary.

If you just want one record with max salary then use `row_number()`.

```
select
    title,
    first_name, 
    last_name,
    salary
from
(select 
    distinct p.title, 
    e.first_name, 
    e.last_name,
    salary,
    dense_rank() over (partition by title order by salary desc) as rnk
 from employees as e
 inner join employees_projects as ep
 on e.id = ep.employee_id
 inner join projects as p
 on p.id = ep.project_id
 group by 1,2,3
 ) t
 where rnk = 1
 order by title
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want one row per title, then use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (p.title) p.title, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary
from employees e join
     employees_projects ep
     on e.id = ep.employee_id join
     projects p
     on p.id = ep.project_id
order by title, salary desc;
```

If you can have multiple titles, then you can use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` in a subquery:

```
select title, first_name, last_name, salary
from (select p.title, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary,
             rank() over (partition by p.title order by e.salary desc) as seqnum
      from employees e join
           employees_projects ep
           on e.id = ep.employee_id join
           projects p
           on p.id = ep.project_id
     ) p
where seqnum = 1
order by title;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the case when group by cant be used meaning you wanna group with no loss of all columns too.

You could simply use below

```
   Select * from (
  select distinct p.title, e.first_name, 
   e.last_name,  e.salary
   , rank()
   Over(partition by 1 order by 
    e.salary desc) 
     ) rn

   from employees as e
   inner join employees_projects as ep
   on e.id = ep.employee_id
   inner join projects as p
   on p.id = ep.project_id) 
  Where rn=1
```